# Javascript graph

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

Hey guys I am trying to learn fetch. I have this problem where I have to get this:

```
<li>Zimmerman, Paul</li>
<li>Yimmerman, Raul</li>
<li>Limmerman, Caul</li>
```

and create those li from scratch

```
async function getPeople() {
  const ul = document.getElementById('people-list-01')
  const response = await fetch('http://example.com/api/people');
  const data = await response.json();
  // console.log(`${data.people[1].lastName}, ${data.people[1].firstName}`);
  // console.log('******',data[0].people.lastName)
  // console.log('--------',data.lastName)
  if (response.ok) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `${data.people[0].lastName}, ${data.people[0].firstName}`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = `${data.people[1].lastName}, ${data.people[1].firstName}`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = `${data.people[2].lastName}, ${data.people[2].firstName}`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    // console.log(ul);
  }
  else {
    console.log('Error')
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
1) GET http://example.com/api/people
       returns a list of three people
         that you use to build list items for #people-list:

      There are not exactly three LIs for #people-list
      + expected - actual

      -1
  +3
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it is useful, this is what's returned by fetch:

```
{
 *      people: [
 *        { id: 1, lastName: 'Zimmerman', firstName: 'Paul' },
 *        { id: 2, lastName: 'Yimmerman', firstName: 'Raul' },
 *        { id: 3, lastName: 'Limmerman', firstName: 'Caul' },
 *        { id: 9, lastName: 'Kimmerman', firstName: 'Maul' },
 *      ]
 *    }
```